# Using an array of char* in a seperate .h file

Tags: c, arrays, string, embedded, avr

I am making an program for an avr with an LCD screen and I need to be able to change languages in the lcd menu.
   I was thinking of creating an array of strings for each language in the form of **__flash const char* array[]**. Then use a pointer to point to the language array required.
  Is there a propper way to do this? I tried using extern but i got something wrong. Also, should i define the size for each string? or leave it like that?

The code I tried is:

> in Language.h file:

```
extern const char* Test_lang[2];
```

> in Language.c file:

```
    const char* Test_lang[2]={"test1","test2"};
```

> in LCD.h file:

```
#include Language.h
```

> in LCD.c file:

static __flash const char** Unicode_text[];

```
void lcd_init(void)
{
.
.
.
 Unicode_text=Test_lang;
}

void lcd_test_print(void)
{
  lcd_print(Unicode_text[1]);
}
```

Comment: *but i got something wrong* - we can't guess what was wrong. Please elaborate.

Comment: What wen't wrong? Could you give us the error message you might have encountered?

Comment: Also show what you tried.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask], and [edit] your post to include an [mcve].

Comment: AVR is a Harvard architecture. That means normal memory reads read from data memory (RAM), but not from program memory (Flash, i.e. ROM). However, the data in `__flash` is stored in program memory, so you need to read that memory with special instructions, e.g. by using `pgm_read_ptr_near` and `strcpy_P` (function names taken from avr-libc, even though your use of `__flash` instead of `PROGMEM` suggests you are using a non-avr-libc environment which probably uses different names).

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow!
I would do the following:

You use an array of arrays of strings to store your language strings.

The first array is the array of languages.
The nested array is the array of strings of each language.
The third "array" is the array of characters (i.e "const char*").

You just have the modify the lengths of each array (the languages array and the strings array).

Example: if you have 3 languages and 5 strings you would write strings[3][5]

```
const int frenchIndex  = 0;
const int englishIndex = 1;

const char* strings[2][2] = {
    // French Text
    { "chien", "bonjour !" },

    // English text
    { "dog", "hello !" }

    //...
};

// Will print "dog" in french then in english
printf("%s\n", strings[frenchIndex][0]);
printf("%s\n", strings[englishIndex][0]);

// Will print "hello" in french then in english
printf("%s\n", strings[frenchIndex][0]);
printf("%s\n", strings[englishIndex][1]);
```

As for your issue, I don't have enough information to help you but I'll if I can!